# Simple exercises about U-tubes

Tags: homework-and-exercises, pressure

I want to solve some exercises involving U-tubes, like

You pour two non-mixing fluids with densities that go like 1:2 into a U-tube. The fluid is 5cm higher in one arm than in the other. Where is the seperating line?

Unfortunately, I don't know any of the formulas one can use for such exercises, all I know is that the pressures must be equal on both sides.
Can you supply me with the most common formula(s) used in this situation?

Comment: What do you mean by 1:2, this ratio is of height, mass, density or what ?

Comment: I'm talking about the ratio of the densities of the two fluids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you poured just one liquid its level would be equal on both sides, now when you pour the liquid on one side, the liquid already present in the U tube rises by lets say h1 height. Lets assume the height of liquid column of the different liquid on other side is of height h2.

We can find out that h2-h1 would be equal to 5 cm (difference in level of two liquids) now to equate pressure on both sides you can use

h1 × d1 × g = h2 × d2 × g 
Here d1 and d2 are respective densities, remember the liquid having column of height h2 will be less dense as it stays above other liquid.

On solving the equation you can find that h1 = 5 cm and h2 = 10 cm. The separation line would be at the bottom of the lighter liquid column ( the one of height h2)

Comment: The exercise states nothing about how much of each liquid gets poured in. However, if you pour much more of the lighter liquid, the separating line would be on the side of the heavier liquid.

Comment: The question does say " The fluid is 5cm higher in one arm than in the other. " If you pour more of that liquid the condition would not be valid. When I solved the question it was independent of amount of liquid ( there was the assumption that the lighter liquid was poured onto denser liquid and that too only on one side of the u-tube ) maybe if you solve it you will get similar results only.